# ASP.NET MVC use model that is a WCF data contract, but with changes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wcf

I am creating an ASP.NET MVC 4 application that relies on a WCF service for its BL.

The WCF reference file that was created holds all the data contracts with the service.

I would like to expose the data contracts to the end clients of my MVC application.

Should I use the data contracts in my controllers instead of creating models?

My end client needs JSON format responses. How can I decorate the data contract references with 
JSON attributes so it will get serialized the way I want it?

Answer (score 0):

Decorate your data contract with `[DataContract]` and decorate your operation contract for example with

```
[WebGet(UriTemplate='...', ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json]
```

The last part will make WCF use the JSON serializer.

Comment: the wcf service does not talk json with my mvc application, this is not what I am asking...

Comment: Hi @AMember, could you find an answer to your question? I am in the same situation. My problem is my MVC application is able to use entities exposed by WCF service but they ignore data Annotations defined for properties.

Answer (score 0):

I think we have found a solution to the problem, our front end team is now sharing contracts with backend WCF service this is actually replacing our models in the MVC application (not all of theme but most of theme). We can decorate our contracts as we like and we take the benifit of both worlds. @Suhani Mody